# C# - Create an instance of a class with generic type parameters without specifying these types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, activator

I have the following code:

```
public static class Typing
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var type = typeof(GenericSuperType<,>);

        type = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(int));
        dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var types = instance.Register();
        
        foreach(var i in types)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public class GenericSuperType<C, R>
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> Register()
    {
        yield return typeof(MiddlewareOne<C, R>);
        yield return typeof(MiddlewareTwo<C, R>);
    }
}

public interface IGenericMiddleware<C, R>
{
    R Execute(C command);
}

public class MiddlewareOne<C, R> : IGenericMiddleware<C, R>
{
    public R Execute(C command)
    {
        return default;
    }
}

public class MiddlewareTwo<C, R> : IGenericMiddleware<C, R>
{
    public R Execute(C command)
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to create an instance of `GenericSuperType<,>` class in order to call the `Register()` method that will basically return some other generic types. The sole purpose for this is to get the types the `Register()` method returns (those types could be different than the ones in the example and would be provided by a user in a method overload). However, in order to do that, I need to provide some types to `GenericSuperrType<,>` (as I do with `int`) here, but then the problem rises - these types can have generic constraints on them, let's say:

```
public class GenericSuperType<C, R> where C : ISomeType
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> Register()
    {
        yield return typeof(MiddlewareOne<C, R>);
        yield return typeof(MiddlewareTwo<C, R>);
    }
}
```

In that case, creating the instance with whatever type will fail.
What I have tried so far is to check the generic constraints on `C` and `R` and act accordingly, something alog those lines (a simple example):

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        var type = typeof(GenericSuperType<,>);

        var defparams = type.GetGenericArguments();
        IList<Type> typeConstraints = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var i in defparams)
        {
            typeConstraints.Add(i.GetGenericParameterConstraints().FirstOrDefault());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < typeConstraints.Count; i++)
        {
            if (typeConstraints[i] == null)
                typeConstraints[i] = typeof(String);
        }

        type = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(int));
        dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var types = instance.Register();
        
        foreach(var i in types)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

And that would work OK but I'd have to cover all possible generic constraints.
The other thing I thought about is: to actually remove the `GenericSuperType<,>` generic type constraints with reflection (if it's actually possible, I think that should be but I'm not great at c# reflection), and then provide some dummy type just to get the types from the `Register()` method. Or maybe just copy the content of the type/class/file into another one without the generic type constraints and call them? I'm looking for solution to this (I know this sounds complicated but I also know that reflection is a powerful tool that would make that possible).

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: You cannot instantiate a generic type without knowing its type parameters, and if a generic type definition has type constraints, you can't just remove them and expect the class to function. Your requirements are truly bizarre. Do you mind me asking what it is you're trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Unfortunately, the solution you have decided on just isn't possible, and really doesn't even make sense. You will have more success if you go back to the original problem that led you here, distill it down to a simple code example and problem statement, and ask about _that_ instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your goal here?  Ultimately, I would say you should create an interface:

```
public interface IRegster
{
    IEnumerable<Type> Register();
}
```

Then have all your class concretes implement this.  Then you don't have to worry about any generic types or creating a dummy instance or anything like that.  You'd just get the types back via the interface.

However, you didn't really say how these generic type classes would be ultimately instantiated later (the real implementation), so I don't know that anyone can give you the perfect advice here.

Comment: The name `Register` for an IEnumerable method is counterintuitive. That name suggests an action, not getting a collection. I understand you're copying the OP's method name, but still.

Comment: @Daniel Lorenz
What I want to achieve is to let a user build their own chain of responsibility consisting of different types implementing the same generic interface, but I also want to let the user define a generic middleware, and the reason I need those types is because of registering them in IoC container to later be later injected in the chain implementation. 
So that both non-generic and generic services could be built.

Comment: @Jania Why not use SimpleInjector? It has built in methods specifically for this - RegisterDecorator